# Does a side-navigation control exist on Tizen?

Tags: user-interface, tizen, tizen-native-app

I am currently trying to imagine the navigation scheme of my first app on Tizen, and I'm wondering if a side navigation control (like the one of the Facebook app on iOS, Android, Windows Phone) exists for native applications on Tizen (even a 3rd party one) ?

Comment: By "side navigation" do you mean a menu located at the left or right side of the screen? If so, I suppose you could use a `ListView` that only covers a small part of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no control that creates side navigation, You should create a custom control

For eg: Create a panel that use touch listener to slide in and out.

`Note: I don't think that there is a side navigation control in android facebook , which is also implemented as custom.(May be another person creates it)`

Edit: Update

Now there are Navigation drawers in android

Comment: You're right about the fact there is no native SideNavigation controls on iOS/Android too, but there are popular 3rd party implementations available.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler with an web app, given that [Tizen Web Apps integrates well with JQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) you could [use a JQuery responsive pannel](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/panels/panel-nav-form.html).  This way you can make your app also available across multiple platforms.